# add 180 entries in table

Tags: sql, loops, insert

I have been trying to give the right 'student' to 180 people in a table, is there a way to do this easily, like with a loop? I imagine something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<=180; i++) {
    INSERT INTO usertorights(UserID, Name, ID,isDeleted)VALUES(i,'Admin',NULL,0);
}
```

I hope somebody will be able to help me, thanks

-Alexander

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I use adminer---

Comment: Do you have another table where we could find the list of these 180 users ?

Comment: Seems like an odd idea, just give a privilege to 180 random people...

Comment: Do you really need number from 0 to 180 or do you want to pick some 181 users for a users table? If the latter, is there any order that should be applied to that or doesn't it matter an some random 181 users are good enough? And how is the user table called and what columns does it have?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a similar result, I used below query

```
INSERT INTO `usertorights`(`UserID`, `Name`, `ID`, `isDeleted`)
SELECT ((ones.n + (10*tens.n) + (100*hundreds.n))) RowNumber, 'Admin', NULL, 0
FROM        (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n)
WHERE CAST(((ones.n + ISNULL(10*tens.n, 0) + ISNULL(100*hundreds.n, 0))) AS DECIMAL(20, 0)) < 180
order by RowNumber;
```

This is faster and efficient

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do that :

```
 DECLARE @nI INTEGER
 SET @nI = 0

 WHILE @nI <= 180 
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.usertorights( UserID, Name, ID, isDeleted) 
   SELECT @nI, 'student', id_people, false FROM people_table)

   SET @nI = @nI + 1
 END
```